# Kentico Event Calendar- Click event for All Dates

Tags: calendar, kentico

I am using Kentico 10.0
I am using an Event Calendar. I do customize the existing calendar and all worked well. 
Now my requirement is to access "calItems_SelectionChanged" event, just as normal asp.net calendar, so that i can fill data to repeater according to the date. Since we are using transformations, i am not able to get the click event.

Nb. i am not using booking events, but am getting all the data plotting. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to clone that webpart and create your own custom events within that webpart.  [This article](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/customizing-web-parts) will help you with cloning and customizing a new webpart. Make necessary name changes as needed.

1. Open the Web parts application.
2. Select the Forms -> On-line form web part in the tree.
3. Click Clone web part () above the tree and enter the following values:

   - New object display name: Form with custom email
   - New object code name: FormWithEmail
   - Clone web part to category: Forms
   - Clone web part files: yes (checked)
   - Cloned web part file name: BizForms/formwithemail.ascx
4. Click Clone.
5. In your visual studio project, modify your new file and add your new code